# newbie needs help i can't find whats wrong. i enter num and it stops

Tags: arrays, visual-c++

```
/*********************************************************************
 *Program Name      :   CSC 110 - 003 Store Unknown Number of Values
 *Author            :   Anthony Small
 *Due Date          :   Nov\17\09
 *Course/Section    :   CSC 110 - 003
 *Program Description:  Store Unknown Number of Values in an Array
 *
 *BEGIN Lab 7 - CSC110-003  Store Unknown Number of Values
 *  init Array to five
 *  init Count to Zero
 *  Get First Value or Quit
 *  WHILE (Value is not Quit)
 *        Store Value into Arry
 *        Add One to Count  
 *  IF    (Array is Full)
 *        Set Value to Quit
 *        Cout Full Message
 *  ELSE  Get Next Value or Quit
 *  End IF
 *  END WHILE
 *  FOR   (Set Value in the Array)
 *        Display Value
 *  END FOR
 *End Lab 7 - Store Unknown Number of Values
 *********************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include <stdlib>
#include <ctime> //or <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//local constants
const int Quit = -1;                            //Sentinal value                            
const int SIZE = 5;                             //Max number of inputs
//local variables
int Num ;
int Count=0;
int Array [SIZE];

//******************************************************************/
// Display Input
cout << "Input first Number or Quit\n";  
cin >> Num;
while   (Num != Quit);

        Array [0] = Num;                        //Store number into array
        Count++;                                //Add one to count
    if (Count==SIZE-1)              
    {
        (Num = Quit);
        cout <<"Array is full";
    }
    else cout <<"Enter next number or quit\n";
      cin>>Num;                                 //Input next number

for (int pos = 0;pos < SIZE; pos++)
    cout << Array [pos];            
return 0;
//end main program
}
```

Comment: Do delete/edit this to make it more readable, otherwise you might get down-voted to coders hell.

Comment: Are you compiling with warnings turned on?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? As mentioned clean it up and provide more detail on what you've tried thus far. Remember you'll only get nudged in the right direction here. You won't get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: Amazing as it may, this thing compiles!

Comment: @MPelletier it's not as amazing as it is a logic error, not a compilation error ;) As for as computer knows, there's nothing wrong with this program.

Comment: And we all know, if it compiles it runs, next stop production. However this "DOESN'T work on my machine".

Comment: i am an old guy in a naw game so i am still learning i do want to say thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

When you do

```
while   (Num != Quit);
```

Do you actually meant:

```
while (Num != Quit)
{
  // Code here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Hint #1 You need to add braces for the while loop... (and remove the semi-column)
Hint #2 You need to use a different subscript (other that systematically 0
        for storing into Array.
```

Comment: should it be SIZE as in the (const in SIZE =5)

Comment: @anthony, think about using Count.

Comment: remember it needs to be different every time through the loop

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the line

```
while   (Num != Quit);
```

also think about what

```
Array [0] = Num;
```

is going to be doing in a loop

what do you think the next output/action is going to be after

```
cout <<"Array is full"
```

indenting, parentheses etc need to be cleaned up to make this do what you want.

Comment: ya still working on style the program should stop after "Array is full"

Answer (score 1):

1. While will loop will only execute 1 time.
2. You will overwrite the first value of the array each time you execute the loop.